# What does dual DAC mode mean for this microcontroller board?

Tags: stm32, dac, dual

I have a [STM32 development board](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00039084-discovery-kit-with-stm32f407vg-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) with [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) manual, and regarding its two DACs somewhere in stm32f4xx_hal_dac.c file, the following is written:

```
  *** DAC Channels ***
  ====================
[..]
STM32F4 devices integrate two 12-bit Digital Analog Converters

The 2 converters (i.e. channel1 & channel2)
can be used independently or simultaneously (dual mode):
  (#) DAC channel1 with DAC_OUT1 (PA4) as output
  (#) DAC channel2 with DAC_OUT2 (PA5) as output
```

And in [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an3126-audio-and-waveform-generation-using-the-dac-in-stm32-products-stmicroelectronics.pdf) application note the following is written:

[image]

I don't understand what is meant by **dual channel**. Does it mean two DACs can act as differential(mirrored) ended output? Does it mean in this mode when the DAC1 is +x Volt the DAC2 will be -x Volt?

Comment: Having the DACs subtract the digital output would be pointless since you can easily do that in software yourself.  Differential _inputs_ can be very useful, but that only requires one DAC, not two.

Comment: Im takling about Differential output

Comment: The output of a 12 bit ADC is a number between 0-4095. What does it mean for a number such as '0' or '100' to be a "differential output"?

Comment: You dont know what is meant by diff output?

Comment: Is this guy wrong at 3:13 https://youtu.be/MweAeTEH1ms?t=193 he claims this mode provides diff output. Is he wrong?

Answer (score 4):

For this MCU in this mode, dual channel DAC means the two DAC converters perform their conversions simultaneously.

Internally, the two DAC output channels will be loaded with new sample data at the same time and their outputs will change at the same time.

Your ST user manual [RM0090](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), explains this in detail. Here's a couple of relevant parts.

On p433, it states:

> In dual DAC channel mode, conversions could be done independently or
> simultaneously when both channels are grouped together for synchronous
> update operations

On p435..436, it explains how data dwords can be read from memory by the DMA Controller and written to the DACs. Each dword can hold a sample for each DAC channel, to support simultaneous conversion. The diagram shown there is below and illustrates the format of each dword with its two 8-bit or 12-bit samples.

[image]

See p440 onwards where it details dual DAC channel conversion. Note that they have a wide variety of operating modes so you'll need to read through the whole section and understand it yourself.

This DMA-fed dual DAC channel capability is very valuable for certain applications, such as motor control, that cannot tolerate staggered update of two DACs.

For example, they could act as differential outputs for the same waveform by feeding each channel with samples of the same waveform but with one sample set a complement of the other.

In reality, they can't be truly simultaneous and there will be some difference in time between the two. That should be specified in the MCU datasheet. The MCU designers clearly think the difference is insignificant or tolerable in the applications they targeted the DACs for.

Comment: I get different info about these. Is this guy wrong here at 3:13 https://youtu.be/MweAeTEH1ms?t=193 ? He says that this mode creates mirrored differential output. I guess he is wrong then. (?)

Comment: So is the video wrong about it?

Comment: @cm64, he doesn't say "this mode creates mirrored differential output". He says it *can* do. I've edited my answer to show that but you know that the site isn't for comment-by-comment personal tutorial, it's a Q&A site not a discussion forum. This answer should give you the starting point and you now need to research this further for yourself. It's all in the datasheets and application notes, which you can look into.

Comment: @cm64 do you believe some random video you found on the interwebs or Q&A site filled with skilled engineers that quote the datasheet and reference manual for you? Besides even if that is not what a dual DAC mode means, as they update simultaneously, you **can** update them with any data so you can use dual mode to **make** a differential DAC.

Comment: @Justme i dont understand the jargon used in datasheets thsts why out of desperatness

Comment: @cm64, it's great that you're learning how this works and I hope this jumps you along but there's a lot of self-learning in engineering, as I'm sure you've seen. Take it to chat if you want to go through this with me/others further.

Comment: in many motor-control applications you need at least two ADC's or two DAC's plus you need to synchronize em (as required by control application math). the signals in range of 100kHz to low MHz have no problem with some ns or ps jitter between the two signals...in general. So this is a typical (motor) control application feature

Comment: @schnedan, great example and a very significant one for these MCUs. Have added it, thanks.